# What went wrong with partitions - data recovery?

Tags: boot, 16.04, data-recovery, partitioning, data-loss

This notebook was used with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for about a year. It was recently closed and opened some days later. However, no mounting medium is found anymore. On a live Ubuntu I get strange partit63ions.

---- edit ----

I found out, why this is strange. The disk I see there is the USB stick (64 Gb) x4. I did not recognize the message "The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
" and get the same behaviour of the stick as described [here](http://The%20driver%20descriptor%20says%20the%20physical%20block%20size%20is%202048%20bytes,%20but%20Linux%20says%20it%20is%20512%20bytes.)

---

[image: GParted].

The [output of boot-repair](http://paste2.org/4xyWw5AB) info gives me no clue besides the partitions got wrecked.

However, the user likes to have his data back. Has anyone any idea how to backup data or get the system running again? I have not started a boot-repair process...

```
# sudo gpart /dev/sda

Begin scan...
End scan.

Checking partitions...
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

Comment: Sorry, this looks like media failure…

Comment: Make a backup of the drive asap before it fails just in case so you can still continue file recovery!! "Dd if=/ dev/sdX of=backup-file.img" then use tools like photorec to recover files from the drive or backup image

Comment: First attempt would be TestDisk. Run it and then report your findings. :)